# How to unit test a form with dynamically added input fields using jest in react?

Tags: reactjs, jestjs

I have created a dynamic form using React. The fields of this form are coming from a db table via an api call inside `useEffect()` hook. The code is below:

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from 'react';

// retrieveAttributes function calls 2 other functions internally
import { retrieveAttributes } from '../services/ConfigService';

const FormPage = () => {
    const [attributesWithValues, setAttributesWithValues] = useState(undefined);
    const [initialAttributesWithValues, setInitialAttributesWithValues] = useState(undefined);
    const [errorMessage, setErrorMessage] = useState('');
    const [successMessage, setSuccessMessage] = useState('');
    const [isSaving, setIsSaving] = useState(false);
    const [isConfigDataLoaded, setIsConfigDataLoaded] = useState(false);

    let searchUrl = 'some-url';
    let type = 'some-type';
    let userId = 'some-user-id';

    useEffect(() => {
        async function getData() {
            let response = undefined;
            try {
                response = await retrieveAttributes(searchUrl, type, userId);
                if (!response || (Array.isArray(response) && response.length < 1)) {
                    setErrorMessage(`Unable to populate config data with values.`);
                } else {
                    setAttributesWithValues(response);
                    setInitialAttributesWithValues(response);
                }

            } catch (error) {
                setErrorMessage(`Error when loading config data. ${error}`);
            } finally {
                setIsConfigDataLoaded(true);
            }
        }

        if (!isConfigDataLoaded) {
            getData();
        }
    }, [attributesWithValues]);

    const renderErrorMessage = () => {
        if (errorMessage) {
            return (
                <div>
                    <h3>ERROR</h3>
                    <div>{errorMessage}</div>
                </div>
            );
        }
    };

    const handleChange = (value, attributeName) => {
        let updatedAttributesWithValues = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(attributesWithValues));

        if (!Array.isArray(updatedAttributesWithValues) || updatedAttributesWithValues.length === 0) {
            updatedAttributesWithValues = [];
            updatedAttributesWithValues.push({
                attributeName: attributeName,
                attributeValue: value
            });
        } else {

            // find existing
            let currentAttributeIndex = attributesWithValues.findIndex(t => t.attributeName === attributeName);

            if (currentAttributeIndex < 0) {
                updatedAttributesWithValues.push({
                    attributeName: attributeName,
                    attributeValue: value
                });
            } else {
                updatedAttributesWithValues[currentAttributeIndex].attributeValue = value;
            }
        }

        setAttributesWithValues(updatedAttributesWithValues);
    }

    const handleClear = () => {
        setErrorMessage('');
        setSuccessMessage('');
        setAttributesWithValues(initialAttributesWithValues);
    };

    const handleSubmit = async (event) => {
        event.preventDefault();
        setErrorMessage('');
        setSuccessMessage('');
        setIsSaving(true);

        console.log(attributesWithValues.some(t => Boolean(t.attributeValue) === false))
        let isInputValid = attributesWithValues.some(t => Boolean(t.attributeValue) === false) ? false : true;

        if (!isInputValid) {
            console.log('setting error message')
            setIsSaving(false);
            setErrorMessage(`One or more input values are missing. Please check.`);
            return;
        } else {
            let response = undefined;
            let formData = [];
            attributesWithValues.forEach(item => {
                formData.push({
                    attributeName: item.attributeName,
                    attributeValue: item.attributeValue
                });
            })
            console.log(formData)
            try {
                response = await submitForm(searchUrl, type, formData);
                if (response) {
                    setSuccessMessage(`Form data submitted successfully.`);
                    return;
                } else {
                    setErrorMessage(`Unable to submit form data.`);
                }
            } catch (error) {
                setErrorMessage(`Error while submitting form data ${error}`);
            } finally {
                setIsSaving(false);
            }
        }



    }

    const renderFormFields = () => {
        // render readonly fields first
        let readOnlyAttributes = attributesWithValues.filter(t => t.isReadOnly === true);
        let editableAttributes = attributesWithValues.filter(t => t.isReadOnly === false);
        let sortedAttributes = [...readOnlyAttributes, ...editableAttributes];

        return sortedAttributes.map((item, index) => {
            if (item.isReadOnly === true) {
                return (
                    <FormGroup
                        id={`${item.attributeName}-${index}`}
                        key={`${item.attributeName}-${index}`}
                        label={`${item.displayText} ( verified )`}
                    >
                        <input type='text' className='form-page-input-textbox-disabled' value={item.attributeValue} readOnly={true} disabled={true} />
                    </FormGroup>
                )
            } else {
                return (
                    <FormGroup
                        id={`${item.attributeName}-${index}`}
                        key={`${item.attributeName}-${index}`}
                        label={item.displayText}
                        errorMessage={`Please enter your ${item.displayText}`}
                    >
                        <Input value={item.attributeValue} onChange={(event) => handleChange(event.target.value, item.attributeName)} />
                    </FormGroup>
                )
            }

        });
    }

    return (
        <div data-testid="form_page" className='dynamic-form-wrapper'>

            {!isConfigDataLoaded && !attributesWithValues &&

                <div>
                    <h3>Loading</h3>
                    <div>{'Loading config data'}</div>
                </div>
            }

            {errorMessage &&
                renderErrorMessage()
            }

            {isSaving &&
                <div>
                    <h3>Saving</h3>
                    <div>{'Saving form data. Please wait...'}</div>
                </div>
            }

            {successMessage &&
                <div>
                    <h3>Success</h3>
                    <div>{successMessage}</div>
                </div>
            }

            {isConfigDataLoaded && !isSaving &&
                <div className='form-buttons-wrapper'>
                    <ButtonBox>
                        <Button onClick={async (event) => await handleSubmit(event)} style={{ margin: '0 10px 0 0' }}>
                            Submit
                        </Button>
                        <Button variant="secondary" onClick={handleClear}>
                            Clear
                        </Button>
                    </ButtonBox>
                </div>
            }

        </div>
    );
};

export default FormPage;
```

The returned data from `retrieveAttributes` function looks like this:

```
[{
    "attributeName": "studentId",
    "attributeValue": "",
    "isReadOnly": false,
    "displayText": "Student Id"
  }, {
    "attributeName": "lastName",
    "attributeValue": "some-last-name",
    "isReadOnly": true,
    "displayText": "Last Name"
  }, {
    "attributeName": "birthDate",
    "attributeValue": "2023-06-07",
    "isReadOnly": true,
    "displayText": "Date of Birth"
  }]
```

The form is working as expected. But I am having problem with unit testing the component. As my code is using `setState` a lot, I am not sure how to write tests for before and after state change scenarios.

Any help/suggestions/guidelines is highly appreciated.

PS: I don't want to use a 3rd party library only to write tests unless there is no other way.

Thanks